# Z-index stacking order

Tags: html, css, z-index

Consider the following jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dHaM8

HTML:

```
<div class="first"><img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300"/></div>
<div class="second"></div>
<div class="third"><p class="test"> test test test </p></div>
```

CSS:

```
.first img {position:fixed; top: 10; left: 10; z-index: 1}
.test {position:fixed; top: 10; left: 10; z-index: 10}
.first {
    background-color: #a6a6a6;
    height: 600px;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-image: url("http://placehold.it/1000x500");
}

.second {
    background-color: #fff;
    min-height: 500px;
    z-index:2;
    position:relative;
}

 .third {
    background-color: #ff0000;
    min-height: 500px;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    position:relative;
    z-index:3;
 }
```

What i am trying to do is:

The kitten should stay fixed within the div "first" which is already achieved if you look at the CSS.

However, the text in the third div is not displaying!

If i set the div higher to that of the kitten, the text will be displayed in the first div which i don't want to happen. I only want it to be displayed in the third div.

Help please.

Comment: You have to put units on your properties, `top: 10` should be something like `top: 10px` etc

Comment: Done: http://jsfiddle.net/zvfxn/
However, my real question remains. I only want the text to be displayed in the third div and not the first two

Answer (score 0):

Give position: relative to the `<p>` tag. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/zvfxn/2/)

```
.test {position:relative; top: 10px; left: 10px; z-index: 10}
```

Comment: That's not what i am seeking. If i set it to relative, it's not simulating the same effect i want, as in the header. Some sort of parallax.. It has to be fixed.